# how to write production server testing for play with OneServerPerSuite

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm trying to test my play 2.5 app after put it on production server. Basically I just want to run the same test written in my ApplicationSpec.scala with the production server settings. I followed the document but failed to create the app instance:

```
import play.api.test.Helpers.{GET => GET_REQUEST, _}
import play.api.test._

class ProductionSpec extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerSuite {

  implicit override lazy val app =
    new GuiceApplicationBuilder().disable[EhCacheModule].router(Router.from {
      case GET(p"/") => Action { play.api.mvc.Results.Ok("ok") }
    }).build()
  "AuthController" should {

      "initialize tables" in {
        val init = route(app, FakeRequest(GET, "/init")).get
        status(init) mustBe OK
      }
  }
}
```

the error is

```
ProductionSpec.scala:25: not found: value GET 
...
ProductionSpec.scala:25: value p is not a member of StringContext
```

How to test the app running on production environment?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mixing the `GETs` and also you are testing on one route and requesting to other

First you have two `GETs` (one in each of these libraries)

[play.api.test.Helpers._](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.4/api/scala/index.html#play.api.test.Helpers$)

[play.api.routing.sird._](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.4/api/scala/index.html#play.api.routing.sird.package)

Second you initialize this route `GET(p"/")` but the you request this one `route(app, FakeRequest(GET, "/init")).get`

I fixed the code and it works

```
import org.scalatestplus.play._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import play.api.routing._
import play.api.routing.sird._
import play.api.cache.EhCacheModule
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient

class ProductionSpec extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerSuite {

  implicit override lazy val app =
    new GuiceApplicationBuilder().disable[EhCacheModule].router(Router.from {
      case play.api.routing.sird.GET(p"/init") => Action { play.api.mvc.Results.Ok("ok") }
    }).build()
  "AuthController" should {

      "initialize tables" in {
        val init = route(app, FakeRequest(play.api.test.Helpers.GET, "/init")).get
        status(init) mustBe OK
      }
  }
}
```

You should be aware when to use each `GET`

I hope this helps